# Unable to create instance of Django model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-2.1

I'm trying to create an instance of this Report model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    """
    A model for storing credit reports pulled from Equifax.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             help_text='User report belongs to.')

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    report = JSONField()
```

However, whenever I try I get this error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /internal/report
Exception Value: 'report' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This happens whether I instantiate the instance using the `Report().save()` method, or the `Report.object.create()` method as follows:

```
    report_obj = Report.objects.create(
        user=user,
        report=report
    )
```

Does anyone have any clue what's going on? There is very clearly a "report" attribute for that class, so why the error?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `JSONFIeld` here comes from? Is it a model field? Or a form field?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the the error and the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715460/unable-to-create-instance-of-django-model#comment96216699_54715460):

> (...) Looks like I imported the form field from DRF instead of the model field of the same name from Django (...)

You did not import a [**`JSONField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) that is a model field, but something else (for example a *form* field, or here a *DRF* field). As a result, Django does not consider `report` to be a field of your `Report` module, it sees it as a "*vanilla*" Python attribute.

You thus should make sure that `JSONField` links to the model field class instead. Adding such field will probably result in another migration to add the field to the database table:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Report(models.Model):
    """
    A model for storing credit reports pulled from Equifax.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=CustomUserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             help_text='User report belongs to.')

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    report = JSONField()
```